# How hot is Plutonium-238 in Radioisotope Thermoelectric Generators (RTGs)?

Tags: nuclear-physics, temperature, radiation, radioactivity

As I understand it, Plutonium-238 is used to provide power through heat generation in radioisotope thermoelectric generators. My question is...  how hot is a pellet of Plutonium-238? Does the heat generated go down as the PLutonium-238 pellet approaches its half life?

Comment: According to my [google search](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=RTG%20temperature), the hot junction of the thermocouple in Voyager's RTG was about 1000°C.  So the radioactive source must have been somewhat hotter than that.  And yes, it gets cooler as it ages.

Comment: The temperature depends on the device, not just the source material.  The RTG is well insulated to keep the temperature high (which increases the efficiency).  A fuel pellet sitting on a bench could be hundreds of degrees cooler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As correctly noted in the comment of @BowlOfRed, the **temperature** of any energy source depends on how well that energy is retained.  You can burn out a 60 W incandescent bulb in a few seconds by burying it in a big box of vermiculite insulation.

The power output of Pu-238 is about 0.5 watts/gram, with a half-life of about 87.7 years. At the end of the 87.7 years, the power output is **still** 0.5 Watts/gram, but there's only half as many grams of Pu-238 left in the original pellet. The rest has changed to U-234 which, with a half-life of 245000 years, doesn't contribute much to the energy output.  More fun facts at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutonium-238